# How can I sign a Debian package created from rust project?

Tags: rust, rust-cargo, deb

I need to sign the `.deb` file I'm creating using `cargo deb`.  So either:

- How do create the `.changes` file from an existing `.deb` file? (`cargo deb` doesn't seem to do that). Or,
- How do I use `debcargo` for a project that is only local and not on https://crates.io?

At the end of the day I want to host our own `apt` repository and I need to have signed packages to do that it.

Comment: it's a long process

Comment: @AdesojiAlu lol